# Natural logarithm - strange output

Tags: c, natural-logarithm

I want to use the natural logaritm in c-language.

I searched google and found a question of this at stackoverflow.com

But When I implement this I get a very cryptic output

here is the code

```
 double x = log(100 / 150);

 printf("d1: %lf", x);
```

and the output:

```
 d1: -1.#INF00
```

What is this? Is it some kind of garbage? What is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Integer division makes `100 / 150` equal to `0`, therefore, `log(0)` is not defined.

Change the code to `log(100.0 / 150.0)`.

Answer (score 0):

If the parameter to log is 0, the output is implementation defined.